# Accessing to a remote mysql db in trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, remote-access

I've a log parsing application and I need to make a query on an another mysql server based on my findings. (ie: what is the userID for this domain)

is it possible to connect another mysql server in a trigger to pull information and update the record on "before insert" event?

Thanks

Comment: Did you check [The FEDERATED Storage Engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/federated-storage-engine.html)?

Comment: thanks for pointing to right direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FEDERATED storage engine solved my issue. I created a table with remote connection and it keeps copy of remote table.

```
CREATE TABLE `domains` (
    `id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `user_id` (`user_id`),
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=FEDERATED
DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
CONNECTION='mysql://user:pass@host:port/database/domains';
```

Thanks to [inhan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/913097/inhan) for showing right direction.

Comment: You're welcome. Just a little note… The (table) data itself is actually a reference to the external source so it's not duplicated. And that's the beauty of it.

Comment: I just test that and yes my local table updates itself automatically. Thanks again.