# Is it possible to sync on-demand table on two mysql servers at different location?

Tags: mysql, synchronization

Looking for suggestions on how can I sync a mysql table over two different server at different location.
We do not want to sync complete database, only want to sync 1 or may be somemore on demand tables.

Comment: Seems like a job for federated storage engine. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/federated-storage-engine.html here's an example from another answer to a similar question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14484452/accessing-to-a-remote-mysql-db-in-trigger

Comment: You can use table replication

Comment: ergest basha is it possible that only table can be replicated, i don't want to replicate DB want replication of a table. Please help me how could I do this.